# How to get the precise value from QJsonObject?

Tags: qt, qdebug

I have made code below.
i want correct value as 44112.25895
but result value is 44112.3
how can i fix this issue?

```
QJsonObject qj{ {"close", 44112.25895} };
qDebug() << qj;
QJsonValue qjv = qj.value("close");
qDebug() << qjv;
qDebug() << qjv.toDouble();
```

result is

QJsonObject({"close":44112.25895})

QJsonValue(double, 44112.3)

44112.3

Comment: Why do you think the value has not the correct valuie? You're using a debug helper function to print a value - if you want another precission you can e.g. print it with std::cout and the desired std::precision

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by [chehrlic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76386539/how-to-get-the-precise-value-from-qjsonobject#comment134697995_76386539) in the comments, the default precision of qDebug() is not what you want. The [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextstream.html#setRealNumberPrecision) says that
the default precision is 6 digits.

You can adjust it using [qSetRealNumberPrecision](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextstream.html#qSetRealNumberPrecision), like this:

```
 qDebug() << qSetRealNumberPrecision( 10 ) << qjv.toDouble();
```

If you want to set this precision only once, then you can define your own qDebug, such as:

```
#define qDebug10() qDebug() << qSetRealNumberPrecision(10)
```

and use it like this:

```
qDebug10() << qSetRealNumberPrecision( 10 ) << qjv.toDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only `qDebug()`'s representation issue.

Try this:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(qjv.toDouble(), 'f', 5);
```

You get: `44112.25895`

Then, try:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(qjv.toDouble(), 'f', 30);
```

Now you get: `44112.258950000003096647560596466064`

It's a floating point issue.